# I am trying to correlate between one colum of a dataset to all columns in another dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, correlation

I have 2 CSV files one called training_data and another called target data Ive read both of them training data contains around 30 columns of data and target data has 1 im trying to correlate between the one column in the target data to all the columns of the training data

```
import pandas as pd
import tarfile
import numpy as np
import csv

#reading in the data
training_data = pd.read_csv(training_data_path)
training_target = pd.read_csv(training_targets_path)

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plotting histogram
training_data.hist(bins=60,figsize=(30,25))
#after reviewing the histograms it can be seen in the histogram of the average household sizes that around 50 counties have a AvgHousehold size of almost 0
#PctSomeCol18_24, PctEmployed16_Over, PctPrivateCoverageAlone all have missing data

display(training_data)
display(training_target)


TARGET_deathRate = training_target["TARGET_deathRate"]
        
corr_matrix=training_data.corr(training_target)
```

Ive tried using the corr function but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use correlation in one data set, therefore first of all you have to join these two datasets and then use the correlation function. for joining you can use concat, append and join which I rather use join:

```
df = training_data.join(training_target)  #joining  datasets
corr_matrix=df.corr()['TARGET_deathRate']
```